# Appending a query string to the url on refresh using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read a label and append its value as a query string once the user hits the refresh button on their browser. The code I have so far is:

```
 function AppendQueryString() {
            var currUrl = document.location;
            var trackingNbr = $("#lblTrackingNbr").text();
           if (window.location.href.indexOf("?TrackingNumber=") <= 0 && trackingNbr !== null) {
                document.location = currUrl + "?TrackingNumber="+ trackingNbr;  
            }
        }

        window.onbeforeunload = AppendQueryString();
```

The problem is, the trackingNbr variable is always null even though the label has the value before I hit refresh. What am I doing wrong or is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: When you refresh the browser, you lose the value from the memory so you need to store it somewhere before refreshing the page. You can try to use "HTML5 local storage".

Comment: you can try `history.pushState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SessionStorage](http://www.geekchamp.com/html5-tutorials/18-html5-session-storage) would be a good solution, with something like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("trackingNbr", trackingNbr);
```

When the refresh button is clicked, you can pull this value back from session storage easily:

```
var trackingNbr = sessionStorage.getItem("trackingNbr");
```

Security: Because this is *session* storage rather than *local* storage, the value will be cleared from the browser when the session ends. Note that only your domain can access whatever you put into either session or local storage. However, a knowledgeable end user can read the value by using developer tools in any of the major browsers.

Comment: As others have already mentioned, this is best handled by Local Storage or sessionStorage. Thanks for this solution.